# Broken Makefile after porting from linux to windows

Tags: windows, makefile

I have a very simple makefile that I ported from Linux to Windows

it only goes inside subfolders and calls other makefiles

```
all:
    $(MAKE) clean
    @(cd apps; $(MAKE))

clean:
    cd apps; $(MAKE) clean;
```

the problem is that I don't understand how the @(command1; command2; command3;) syntax works and I'm unable to make it work even with the simplest of commands

For instance

```
all:
    dir
```

works fine and it outputs the contents of the directory (and I'm in the right one)

```
all:
    cd apps; dir
```

Does not work, it outputs

> cd apps; dir The system cannot find the path specified.

Even worse if I keep the parentheses:

```
all:
    @(dir)
```

outputs

> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, (dir), ...) failed. make (e=2): The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

Can somebody please point me to the proper documentation? I know it must be very simple but all the guesswork so far failed and the documentation is too huge to read it all. I tried but I couldn't find what I'm looking for

Thanks

Comment: The semicolon separates commands in bash but is just a normal character that becomes part of the command line in cmd (Windows).

Comment: The at symbol `@` is used in Makefiles to suppress echoing of the commands in the recipes.

Comment: I suspected that! What is its windows batch equivalent? The ampersand?

Comment: Just use `$(MAKE) -C apps clean` instead, no need for multiple commands.